# Dividing rows of dataframe to simple rows in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have this schema and I would like to split the inside of result into columns in order to have col1: EventCode, col2: Message, etc... I'm using Pyspark, I tried the explode function but it doesn't seem to work on structType, is there a way to do this in Spark ?

```
root
 |-- result: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- EventCode: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Message: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _bkt: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _cd: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _indextime: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _pre_msg: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _raw: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _serial: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _si: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- _sourcetype: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _time: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- host: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- index: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- linecount: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- source: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- sourcetype: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 1):

To divide rows of dataframe to simple rows is easy. All you have to do is select all columns from dataframe and assign it to another dataframe. Something like this:

```
simpleDF = df.select("result.*")
```

It will convert the above given schema into following schema:

```
simpleDF.printSchema

root
 |-- EventCode: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Message: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _bkt: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _cd: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _indextime: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _pre_msg: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _raw: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _serial: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _si: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- _sourcetype: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _time: string (nullable = true)
 |-- host: string (nullable = true)
 |-- index: string (nullable = true)
 |-- linecount: string (nullable = true)
 |-- source: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sourcetype: string (nullable = true)
```